# Machine Learning to predict user engagements

Tags: python, machine-learning

i am working on a php project where i need to predict user like or report of a post based on the previous activity history.once i predict a new post whether user will like or report i can automate it without actually user have to manually done it.in order to achieve that feature i decided to use python along with php as an API service.

here is my table structure

```
post table

id  post_title  content   sentiment  channel 
 1   post1      content1    .92      facebook
 2   post2      content2    .60      facebook
 3   post3      content3    .40      twitter
 4   post4      content4    .98      instagram

post_actions

id  post_id user_id liked reported time_done
 1   1       1       1      0       4:00pm
 2   2       1       0      1       2:00pm
 3   1       2       0      1       3:00pm
 4   3       1       1      0       4:00pm
```

here i want to predict lets say for user_id 1 whenever a new post arrives he likes or not.same case applicable for reported as well. i have made a lot of researches ended up with recommender system.i also further understand this is a content based recommender if i was not wrong.

my reference here as follows

1)https://towardsdatascience.com/wine-ratings-prediction-using-machine-learning-ce259832b321

2)https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-from-scratch-a-content-based-movie-recommender-with-natural-language-processing-25ad400eb243

3)https://medium.com/@adamlouly/nlp-based-recommender-system-without-user-preferences-7077f4474107

my features for ML are post_title,content,sentiment,channel,time_done
My questions are

1)is recommender system is a good approach for this problem?

2)if yes then which is better cosine similarity or training with randomforest classifier?

3)can i use time as a feature?should that work?

i am new to python.please help,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a classic recommender system problem. There are many approaches to solve this problem, and I recommend starting with this [article](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~atuzhili/pdf/TKDE-Paper-as-Printed.pdf). Generally, there are two approaches in recommender systems - model-based and memory-based. In my experience, model-based methods perform much better than memory-based ones. There's a nice summary [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-recommender-systems-6c66cf15ada) regarding the different models and solutions.

I wouldn't recommend neither cosine similarity nor random forest. Cosine similarity gives a very week similarity score, and the random forest is not personalized per user. However, if these are the only two tools that you know - use the random forest. Generally, I would recommend using matrix factorization, that tends to give better accuracy.

The time feature is a very important feature. You should create several KPIs that encapsulate the effect of the time factor. For example the hour and weekday of the post, the time between the user login and the post creation and so forth.

Note that recommender systems are a huge area of research - so you cannot get all of the answers from one post. You will need to do some research and understand how the data should be summarized, how the user profile and item profiles behave and much more. If you are new to python, I would also recommend reviewing the R script language, which has many tools for recommender systems and is more straight forward for beginners than Python. (I did my recommender systems PhD thesis using R)

Comment: Thank you for your help.i would like to know what if a new post called post5 which is only accessible to user 1 not for user 2 so i don't want to recommend those to user 2.i am thinking of using flask as api.sounds like i need dynamci pkl file.more information can be found in this link.please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156966/training-personalized-based-machine-learning-models